# finditer with re.DOTALL starts analysis from span=(16,17). Why?

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to dismember a text file to sections with findall sort or action.
I need backreferencing so I opt for finditer.
Since I'm processing a text file w multiple lines - I need re.DOTALL. It works fine as long as the match doesn't start in first 16 characters.
The (over)simplified problem example:

```
r=re.compile(r'[0-9]')
[print(i) for i in r.finditer('01234567890123456789',re.DOTALL)]
```

The output is:

```
<re.Match object; span=(16, 17), match='6'>
<re.Match object; span=(17, 18), match='7'>
<re.Match object; span=(18, 19), match='8'>
<re.Match object; span=(19, 20), match='9'>
[None, None, None, None]
```

I expect 20 matches and not 4.
I guess that I could achieve my objective with re.MULTILINE but I'd like preserve my faith in python re functions and/or my understanding of them.
Please advice.

KonradP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did was something that happens to the best of us, so promise not to bang your head against the wall?

`re.DOTALL` is correct, but it is not the parameter for the function you wanted. You need to put it in the compile function, like so:

```
r=re.compile(r'[0-9]', re.DOTALL)
```

Fun fact: re.DOTALL in its integer format has the value `16`. Wanna guess why the first 16 matches of the input were ignored?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `re.DOTALL` is an integer with value 16.

```py
print(isinstance(re.DOTALL, int))    # True
print(re.DOTALL)                     # <RegexFlag.DOTALL: 16>
```

The second argument of `re.finditer` is the start index to search for. You should be passing the flags when compiling the Regex pattern, so the following

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]', re.DOTALL)

for match in pattern.finditer('01234567890123456789'):
    print(match)
```

would run as expected.